# OS X 10.10 install can't verify (Registered developer)

Tags: macos, installation, osx-yosemite

Well this is embarassing...
I'm a college student with an apple developer's license.
I'm currently stuck in the CMD+R recovery partition.

I installed 10.10 successfully earlier today. Then I got the bright idea to format my drive and do a clean install of Yosemite. When I clicked the 'Reinstall OS X' button in the recovery screen I recieved a message telling me that my computer cannot be verified with apple. I'm guessing this is because the recovery drive cannot recognize or download/install my developer certs.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? I'd prefer to install 10.10 but I'll roll back to 10.9 if absolutely necessary.

EDIT:
I solved my problem by doing an internet recovery (Cmd+Opt+R at startup). From there I installed 10.8 and re-installed 10.10 from the mac app store.

Comment: Did you solve it? I am having the same issue. Downloaded it from App Store using redemption code. I want to erase and install as it is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by re-installing 10.8 onto my main partition and updating to 10.10 from there.

Answer (score 6):

If you downloaded it from the developer site, you should have went through redeeming a code step, then Yosemite should be in your purchased app list. Are you sure you are using the account you redeemed the code? If you get the image from someone else, you probably want to redeem the code from the developer center.

Comment: Yes, I did redeem it through the developer site

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a clean install by booting to an external Mountain Lion disk and running the installer from there. More info: http://themainthread.com/blog/2014/06/clean-install-yosemite.html

Comment: Actually it does. Install by booting from an external drive and running the installer from there.

Answer (score 0):

Since apple has not released OS X Yosemite to the public they can't verify the software because the recovery mode disk utility is for non developers, the software is not in the apple system yet. You should just make a bootable usb and do a clean install of OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Not a valid answer , please add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Items to try:

1) Repair Permissions (better if booted into Recovery HD)
2) Resync time with Apple's Servers via System Preferences

...if all else fails, you can nuke and pave, or create a bootable USB installer.